# Handle CURL headers before downloading body

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP and CURL (unless there is a better alternative then CURL in this case), is it possible to have a php function handle the header response before downloading the file?

For example:

I have a script that downloads and processes urls supplied by the user.  I would like to add a check so that if the file is not valid for my process (not a text file, too large, etc),the CURL request would be cancelled before the server wastes time downloading the file.

**Update: Solution**
PEAR class HTTP_Request2: http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/
Gives you the ability to set observers to the connection and throw exceptions to cancel anytime.  Works perfectly for my needs!

Comment: I did find an option in cURL "CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION" that lets you set a callback function for headers, however you cannot cancel the request from inside the callback.  You get the error: "Attempt to close cURL handle from a callback"

Comment: in good programming designs, one should never throw an exception for "normal" operations, as usually exception are algorithmically expensive. They should only be for operations that shall happen rarely, like errors or incorrect behaviour.

Comment: To abort downloading the response stream from within a callback function defined for `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` or other `CURLOPT_*FUNCTION` option, just have your callback return `-1`.

Answer (score 6):

Using cURL, do a HTTP HEAD request to check the headers, then if it is valid (the status is 200) do the full HTTP GET request.

The basic option you must set is `CURLOPT_NOBODY`, which changes the requested to the type HEAD

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Then after executing the query, you need to check the return status which can be done using [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

```
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: No. It explains exactly how to do it.

Comment: That's true, but it does seem wasteful to have to send two requests/connections for every url.

Comment: It might be more wasteful to issue a GET request only to throw away the body when the content-type doesn't match, because you are not supposed to abort the request (that's why the HEAD method exists).

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old topic but just in case people comes here in the future.

With CURL, you can use [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php), who let's you place a callback that will be called as soon as the body response starts coming and needs to be written. In that moment you can read the headers and cancel the process and the body will not be downloaded. All in one request.

For a deeper look and code examples see [PHP/Curl: inspecting response headers before downloading body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390319/php-curl-inspecting-response-headers-before-downloading-body)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how you can solve it:

```
// Include the Auth string in the headers
// Together with the API version being used
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth,
    "GData-Version: 3.0",
);

// Make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Parse the response
$response = simplexml_load_string($response);

// Output data
foreach($response->entry as $file)
{
       //now you can do what ever if file type is a txt
        //if($file->title =="txt")
        // do something
        else
        // do soething
    echo "File: " . $file->title . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $file->content["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Author: " . $file->author->name . "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: That downloads the body of the url in addition to the headers.  The point is get the headers and then have the option to stop the connection before the body if needed.