# Does cURL NOBODY actually fetch the body?

Tags: php, curl

I'm not sure if this function in CURL just strips the response body out but still load it fully.
Is that true? I don't want to waste bandwidth, I just want the headers.

Comment: CURLOPT_NOBODY changes the http verb into HEAD which just gets headers. From the related links on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retreival-in-php-via-curl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849723/handle-curl-headers-before-downloading-body

Answer (score 4):

`CURLOPT_NOBODY` will send a `HEAD` request to web server. The server should respond with just the HTTP headers and no body content.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.

Comment: The server *should*, but in some cases (e.g. dynamic generated content) it might *not* do that.

Answer (score 1):

It will only load the headers, it won't load the body of the requested document.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in official doc, It will not download the body if you enable it

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html

> **DESCRIPTION** A long parameter set to 1 tells libcurl to not include the
>   body-part in the output when doing what would otherwise be a download.
>   For HTTP(S), this makes libcurl do a HEAD request. For most other
>   protocols it means just not asking to transfer the body data.
>
> **Enabling this option means asking for a download but without a body.**