# Does CURLOPT_NOBODY still download the body - using bandwidth

Tags: php, curl

I'm performing a cURL post with PHP and trying to reduce the amount of bandwidth I am using. I don't need anything back from the remote site I am posting to since I control the remote site all my tracking to make sure the post was successful is done on the receiving end.

My questions is...

When you set CURLOPT_NOBODY to TRUE:

Does it still download the body and simply not return it to you?

OR

Does it ignore the body and not download it at all?

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789940/is-curl-nobody-actually-fetch-the-body

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[From the PHP manual on `curl_setopt`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) (emphasis mine):

> `CURLOPT_NOBODY`: TRUE to exclude the body from the output. Request method is then set to **HEAD**. Changing this to FALSE does not change it to GET.

So, the answer is no. It won't download the body then because it is a [HTTP HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) then:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.