# CURLOPT_NOBODY influence the response header when i use curl

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

my problem code

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/qyT7G6gVFSs');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($data);
```

the response is

string(241) "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Tengine/1.4.0
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 15:53:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=GBK
Content-Length: 1085
Connection: close
appSrv: itemview-app4-app_admin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Allow: GET
"

then my correct code is

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/qyT7G6gVFSs');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($data);
```

the result is
string(313) "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Tengine/1.4.0
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 16:17:25 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
appSrv: itemview-app5-app_admin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Pragma: No-Cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://tv.tudou.com/

"

yes it's just the CURLOPT_NOBODY,anybody can tell me why?please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a CURLOPT_NOBODY, it actually performs a different type of request [Does CURLOPT_NOBODY still download the body - using bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834143/does-curlopt-nobody-still-download-the-body-using-bandwidth)  It looks like the server you are curling against does not support this type of request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
            //cURL set options
            //cURL options array set
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $this->URL,              #set URL address
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $this->UserAgent,  #set UserAgent to get right content like a browser
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         #redirection result from output to string as curl_exec() result
                CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt',    #set cookie to skip site ads
                CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookiesjar.txt',  #set cookie to skip site ads
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,         #follow by header location
                CURLOPT_HEADER => true,                 #get header (not head) of site
                CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,           #close connection, connection is not pooled to reuse
                CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,          #force the use of a new connection instead of a cached one
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false         #can get protected content SSL
            );
            //set array options to object $curl
            curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
```