# curl request header info and not the contents of the page

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I'm writing a script that will use cURL to check a number of links. I know I can use `curl_getinfo()` to get the http status code, but I'm not sure if that requests the entire page or just the response with the headers. Is there any curl option or setting I can use to only request the headers of the URL (i.e. 404 not found, moved, etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct cURL to not download the contents (body) of the request by setting the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option to `TRUE` - see
[Does CURLOPT_NOBODY still download the body - using bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834143/does-curlopt-nobody-still-download-the-body-using-bandwidth)

p.s. `curl_getinfo()` does not make requests - it gets information from requests that have already been executed.