# cURL source retrieval (ignore files/images)

Tags: php, curl

We've developed an irc bot in php which, (among many other functions), will respond with the page title of any url a user sends to the channel. The problem i'm having is that when someone puts the url of an image or a file, the bot tries to retrieve that file or image.

I'm trying to determine the best way to go about solving this issue. Should I filter the url inputs and regex them for all possible file types? That seems daunting and exhaustive, to say the least. If anyone caught on to it they could simply put a huge file somewhere with a senseless extension and then say that url in the channel and time the bot out.

I feel like i'm missing a curl option which could make it simply ignore file retrievals which aren't simply ascii in nature. Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: Why do people insist on applying `code formatting` to random words? Moreover, why do people accept these edits?!

Comment: I didn't use any code formatting in my question..

Comment: One idea could be that you do a HEAD request first and if the content type is text/html you download it otherwise you don't. Or you could just read the first 1000 characters (or something small) and check if the title is there. And if isn't you assume it is something else than html.

Comment: @dns I was referring to the edit, which I rolled back.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Oh ok, didn't see the first edit

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390319/php-curl-inspecting-response-headers-before-downloading-body Exactly what WizKid said, but instead of two requests, you simply exit if the response isn't `text/html`.

Comment: @WizKid, I agree that the HEAD request is the best option. If something is different from type "text/html" it doesn't deserve the pity download it

Comment: @WizKid Yeah, I considered only reading X amount of chars, but I know some pages have ridiculously long metadata coding and tons of javascript in the head of their pages, and the title can sometimes be over 2000 chars into the page. But I do like the idea of the head request to check out the page first.

Comment: Ok @WizKid I'll do that, I can make that work. Put it as answer and i'll accept that. I appreciate the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea could be that you do a HEAD request first and if the content type is text/html you download it otherwise you don't. Or you could just read the first 1000 characters (or something small) and check if the title is there. And if isn't you assume it is something else than html.